# Como sumar una fila antes en mysql?

Tags: mysql

actualmente tengo una tabla llamada "trabajos" que tiene las siguientes filas:

id | tipo_trabajo | descripcion | region | fecha | semana

aca una vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces haciendo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  pc.region,
    pc.semana,
    pc.tipo_trabajo,
    IFNULL(count(t.id),0) nro_trabajos
FROM (SELECT *
        FROM (select region from trabajos group by region) t1
        CROSS JOIN (select semana from trabajos group by semana) t2
        CROSS JOIN (select tipo_trabajo from trabajos group by tipo_trabajo) t3
    ) pc
LEFT JOIN trabajos t
    ON pc.region = t.region
    AND pc.semana = t.semana
    AND pc.tipo_trabajo = t.tipo_trabajo
GROUP BY pc.region,
         pc.tipo_trabajo,
         pc.semana
```

me muestra una tabla que contiene lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con esto puedo obtener los trabajos que se hicieron y los que no(que no se tienen registrados)

pero como podria hacer para que esta consulta que tengo, tambien obtenga una columna que sume lo lo que se tuvo anteriormente. algo asi:

```
 region | semana | tipo_trabajo | nro_trabajos | acumulado
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 Centro | 1      | Auditoria    | 0            | 0

 Centro | 2      | Auditoria    | 5            | 5

 Centro | 3      | Auditoria    | 0            | 5

 Centro | 1      | Mantenimiento| 3            | 3

 Centro | 2      | Mantenimiento| 3            | 6

 Centro | 3      | Mantenimiento| 4            | 10
```

la tabla que presento consta de lo siguiente

```
 -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
 -- version 4.8.0.1
 -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
 --
 -- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
 -- Tiempo de generación: 10-06-2019 a las 16:49:59
 -- Versión del servidor: 10.1.32-MariaDB
 -- Versión de PHP: 7.2.5

  SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
  SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
  START TRANSACTION;
  SET time_zone = "+00:00";


  /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
  /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
  /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
  /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

  --
  -- Base de datos: `data`
  --

  -- --------------------------------------------------------

  --
  -- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `trabajos`
  --

  CREATE TABLE `trabajos` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `tipo_trabajo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `descripcion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
     `region` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     `fecha` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     `semana` varchar(20) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

  --
  -- Volcado de datos para la tabla `trabajos`
  --

  INSERT INTO `trabajos` (`id`, `tipo_trabajo`, `descripcion`, `region`, `fecha`, `semana`) VALUES
   (1, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '1/01/2019', '1'),
   (2, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '1/01/2019', '1'),
   (3, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'LIMA', '1/01/2019', '1'),
   (4, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '3/01/2019', '1'),
   (5, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'LIMA', '3/01/2019', '1'),
   (6, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'LIMA', '4/01/2019', '1'),
   (7, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'LIMA', '5/01/2019', '1'),
   (8, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'CENTRO', '7/01/2019', '2'),
   (9, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'CENTRO', '8/01/2019', '2'),
   (10, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'CENTRO', '8/01/2019', '2'),
   (11, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'CENTRO', '8/01/2019', '2'),
   (12, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '8/01/2019', '2'),
   (13, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '8/01/2019', '2'),
   (14, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '9/01/2019', '2'),
    (15, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '9/01/2019', '2'),
   (16, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'LIMA', '9/01/2019', '2'),
   (17, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '10/01/2019', '2'),
   (18, 'Auditoria', 'Audit a los equipos de alta gama', 'CENTRO', '11/01/2019', '2'),
   (19, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '11/01/2019', '2'),
   (20, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '11/01/2019', '2'),
   (21, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '11/01/2019', '2'),
   (22, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '11/01/2019', '2'),
   (23, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '11/01/2019', '2'),
   (24, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '12/01/2019', '2'),
  (25, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '15/01/2019', '3'),
  (26, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '15/01/2019', '3'),
  (27, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '15/01/2019', '3'),
  (28, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '16/01/2019', '3'),
  (29, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'LIMA', '16/01/2019', '3'),
  (30, 'Mantenimiento', 'Se realizo mantenimiento de los equipos', 'CENTRO', '17/01/2019', '3');

  --
  -- Índices para tablas volcadas
  --

  --
  -- Indices de la tabla `trabajos`
  --
  ALTER TABLE `trabajos`
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

  --
  -- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
  --

  --
  -- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `trabajos`
  --
   ALTER TABLE `trabajos`
   MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=31;
   COMMIT;

   /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
   /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
   /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Eso no te quedaria mas facil hacerlo en el Back-end?

Comment: esta consulta que realizo se almacenara en una vista, y esta vista la llamo en el power bi, que me sirve para mostrar indicadores

Comment: ¿puedes poner en tu pregunta por favor algunos datos de ejemplo en la tabla trabajos? Preferentemente a manera de insert para poder replicar tu salida y a su vez generar mi propuesta.

Comment: ¿Que versión de mysql estás usando?

Comment: @AlvaroC.la version es 4.8.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Envuelve tu query con el lo siguiente:

```
SELECT region
     , semana
     , tipo_trabajo
     , nro_trabajos
     , @acumulado := if( (region,tipo_trabajo)=(@region,@trabajo)
                       , @acumulado
                       , ifnull( concat( @region := region
                                       , @trabajo := tipo_trabajo
                                       , null
                                       )
                               , 0
                               )
                       ) 
                   + nro_trabajos acumulado    
  FROM ( <tu query>
       ) t
    JOIN ( SELECT @acumulado := 0
                , @region  := null
                , @trabajo := null
         ) vars
```

Usamos variables de usuario, una para llevar el acumulado y otras 2 para detectar el cambio de grupo; el `JOIN` es para inicializarlas. Dentro del `if` hacemos una comparación de tuplas, si estamos en el mismo grupo sigue acumulando, de lo contrario el acumulado es `0` al concatenar dos asignaciones al grupo nuevo con `null`, el truco es reasignar variables a la vez de regresar un cero. `nro_trabajos` siempre suma para el acumulado.

Comment: mencionas que ponga mi query dentro de tu codigo, pero en tu codigo estas llamando a "nro_trabajos", pero esa columna no existe

Comment: Es el alias que usas para el count a `t.id`, tal y como esta tu query en la pregunta.

Comment: si, lo encontre. ingrese el codigo que me mencionaste pero en la columna "acumulado" me sale lo mismo que en la columna "nro_trabajos", pero +1 unidad... a que se debe esto?

Comment: Ni idea, si agregas scripts para crear la tabla con datos de ejemplo ó preparas algo como un SQLFiddle lo puedo revisar.

Comment: acabo de agregar el contenido de mi tabla "trabajos"

Comment: Respuesta actualizada, corregí el manejo de grupos quitando la semana y cambié la técnica para actualizar el cambio de grupo a una mas acorde para cadenas.

Comment: Uff, jamas hubiera imaginado todo eso... sorprendente.